# supabase row level security for append only table

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, supabase-database

What I'm trying to do is to have a table that assigns a subscription to a user. All the samples I found so far do this via:

```
(auth.uid() = user_id)
```

However I would like to keep track of reassignments. With a table structured like this:

```dart
// assigments //

user_id | subscription_id | comment    | created_at
---------------------------------------------------
3       | 1001            | re-assign  | 2023-06-06
---------------------------------------------------
2       | 1002            | intial     | 2023-06-05
---------------------------------------------------
1       | 1001            | intial     | 2023-06-05
---------------------------------------------------
```

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around writing policy for this. I think it needs to be something like

```
auth.uid() IN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (subscription_id) user_id FROM assignments ORDER BY created_at)
```

Is this the right track? `auth.uid() IN (...)` feels super inefficient. Is it possible to first see if there is a row that matches `user_id == auth.uid()` and to a subquery on the resulting subscription_id with a `ORDER BY created_at, LIMIT 1` and somehow use the result for the `auth.uid()` comparison?

Comment: Does a user and the subscription have one to one relationship, or one to many?

Comment: They do have a one to one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If the user and "active" subscription have one to one relationship, then you should be able to do something like this

```sql
auth.uid() = (SELECT a.user_id
  FROM assignments a
  WHERE a.subscription_id = assignments.subscription_id
  ORDER BY a.created_at desc limit 1)
```

Within the `a.subscription_id = assignments.subscription_id`, `a.subscription_id` is the subscription id from the sub query, and `assignments.subscription_id` is the current row that is being evaluated within this RLS policy.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [@dshukertjr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421443/23028) found a solution. Trying to run a sub query on the table for which the policy is written results in  `infinite recursion detected in policy for relation "assignments" (Error: 42P17)`. With this I was able to find https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/3328 and https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/1138.

The answer is to use a function that bypasses RLS to do the check.

```
BEGIN
        RETURN _user_id IN (
            SELECT user_id
            FROM assignments
            WHERE subscription_id = _subscription_id
            ORDER BY created_at DESC
            LIMIT 1
        );
END;
```

And use the function in the policy like:

```
is_subscription_owner(auth.uid(), subscription_id)
```